# Emoji and ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, emoji

I've been playing around with this issue for a while now. What I'm trying to achieve is to save to the MySQL database, and output to the window thereafter, the generally confirmed emoji such as    (yep, 21st century problems)

After much of the tinkering around and following various tutorials and answers found on this site I have managed to achieve the ability to save them to the database.

I have a simple self submitting form as an example, and a MySQL database configured as UTF8mb4. If I paste emoji to the textarea and hit submit, it does save onto the database table as it should. When viewed using phpmyadmin, it does show the test emoji saved as expected. However, when I use cfquery to get the string from the database and output it to the window, it shows a simple '?'.

Any ideas?

Extra information:
my test window does have the following tags included at the top:

```
<cfset setEncoding("form","utf-8")> 
<cfcontent type="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "utf-8">
```

The database connection string also has `allowMultiQueries=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8`, which seems to be working, as I can successfully insert the emoji. What am I missing?

Edit 1

As per request, below is the code used to select string containing the emoji from the database and to output it to the window:

```
<cfquery name="get_ci" datasource="test" username="#application.db_username#" password="#application.db_password#">
       SELECT _string
       FROM test_table
       WHERE _id = 1
       LIMIT 1
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#get_ci._string#</cfoutput>
```

Edit 2 (solution)

After much deliberation and there was certainly a lot of it here's the solution that at least worked for me. In order to upgrade the MySQL server to support UTF8mb4 I used this guide: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 (please note that was done way before starting this thread and is not the solution to the issue raised). However, after getting it to work on our hosted VPS with the help of its technicians, I have managed to successfully match the settings and here's the answer:
the guide asked to update my.ini the settings to the following:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

However, the handshake and collation ones were the two that were tripping the entire operation. As soon as I commented them out, wola! So just in case somebody else is struggling with this issue and resorting to … Try commenting these settings out and see if it works.

Updated my.ini with applied comments:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
#character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
#collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the cfquery code and the cf code that outputs the results?

Comment: Try saving your file with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @Pankaj as mentioned in my post, I do not have any problems saving the data to database. The saved emoji is visible via phpMyAdmin, if that is what you meant

Comment: Weird.. worked for me with CF11/MySQL8.  Maybe try a few sanity checks? 1) If you've inserted the values multiple times, make sure the LIMIT 1 query is returning the *latest* record. 2) Self post the form and just output the FORM.textArea value to the screen. Does it display correctly? 3) Verify the column charset/collation is really set to UTF8mb4  4) Are the values inserted using cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_**nvarchar**"?

Comment: Look at your system's default encoding. Does it behave the same on all systems you view it on? It definitely sounds like an encoding issue.

Comment: @Ageax 1 - query is correct, 2 - if form is self-posted and FORM variable output to the screen, it displays correctly, 3 - all collations are set correctly and I am able to see the saved emoji via phpMyAdmin, 4 - yep

Comment: @Shawn Would it matter if I am able to output the form data right after submission? It only fails if I try to select it from the database

Comment: What are you using to select it and display your select? There may encoding issues in whatever you're using to display your select.

Comment: Which settings did you comment out?( Maybe it is formatting, but I don't see it in the above)

Comment: @Ageax sorry, it was in the description under the code. I added an updated code block to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, that is more clear. You might want to post it as an "answer" so the solution is more obvious and folks can also vote on it too :)

Comment: @Ageax alright, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution:

After much deliberation and there was certainly a lot of it here's the solution that at least worked for me. In order to upgrade the MySQL server to support UTF8mb4 I used this guide: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 (please note that was done way before starting this thread and is not the solution to the issue raised). However, after getting it to work on our hosted VPS with the help of its technicians, I have managed to successfully match the settings and here's the answer: the guide asked to update my.ini the settings to the following:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

However, the handshake and collation ones were the two that were tripping the entire operation. As soon as I commented them out, wola! So just in case somebody else is struggling with this issue and resorting to … Try commenting these settings out and see if it works.

Updated my.ini with applied comments:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
#character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
#collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. It's curious though. You were already able to store the emojis previous to the ini change. Anyway, glad you got it working.

Comment: @Jules yes, that was the part that drove me crazy. I was able to store it, which meant that everything was compatible with the utf8mb4, but when trying to retrieve kept getting the '?' instead of the actual image. The corrections to the my.ini file helped hence happy me.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your ColdFusion administrator > Server Settings > Java and JVM.
In your JVM Arguments add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Then restart ColdFusion.

And in the MySQL database, the table's encoding should be `utf8mb4`.
I don't remember if the fields' Encoding and Collation have to set as that as well.

Comment: Hi @Jules, thanks for the input. Added the line to JVM settings, but it changed nothing. MySQL encoding is already set toutf8mb4 everywhere it should be (according to multiple tutorials and posts found around the net)

Comment: Since you can see the emoji in the database, we know it's being stored correctly. In your text editor, make sure your CFM file have encoding set to UTF-8. In your ColdFusion DSN, make sure your have Unicode Support enabled. In your HTML file, make sure the meta content type is UTF-8... or do so in Application.cfc with `<cfheader name="content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`